# Get the current upper limit value for nvarchar2 in an Oracle 12c db

Tags: oracle-12c

Starting from 12c, Oracle Database provides a way to control the max byte-size of a `NVARCHAR2` column. To use up to 32767 bytes instead of 4000, one has to set the parameter `max_string_size` to `EXTENDED`.

Now, let's say I create dynamically tables from a Java application and I always want to use the max size for an `NVARCHAR2` column, how can I get the max current value?

I know, I can do a select like

```
SELECT value
  FROM v$parameter
 WHERE name = 'max_string_size'
```

and check if the value is `EXTENDED`, but to me it looks more professional and robust if I can replace a statement like

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn NVARCHAR2(32767))
```

with

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn NVARCHAR2($system_var_for_max_size))
```

So, is there any system variable that stores the max size that I can use as in the previous example?

Comment: To my knowledge, checking `max_string_size` is the only way to do it.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `NVARCHAR2(max)` behaves appropriately?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ: `NVARCHAR2(max)` is invalid in Oracle

Comment: I've been using other RDBMSes too much! 

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the feedbacks. It is a pity that the Oracle crew did not provide such a feature. That's it :)